# Azure blob download to stream has errors

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to download an Azure blob to MemoryStream, and I am getting error "'memoryStream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'". But I am able to download to file.

The code snippet is below

```
private static void GetExcelBlobData(string filename, string connectionString, string containerName)
        {
            // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

            // Retrieve reference to a blob named "test.xlsx"
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlobReference = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

            DataSet ds;
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                //downloads blob's content to a stream
                blockBlobReference.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
            }
        }
```

Debug console error on line "blockBlobReference.DownloadToStream(memoryStream)" is shown

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

[image: Error in MemoryStream]

Comment: I ran your sample locally using a storage account in Azure, containing a test container with a test Excel file. `DowloadToStream` worked fine and `memoryStream` contained the data from the file afterwards. In my opinion, the problem is not in your code but elsewhere. Using the same connectionstring, are you able to access your blob using some other client, like AzCopy or Azure Storage Explorer?

Comment: Are you getting an exception when running the code, or are you getting the exception when you want to traverse the MemoryStream object's properties in the watch? If you look at the blockBlobReference: do the storage account, container and blob exist?

Comment: Sorry guys. With your clue when I debug, in fact the stream was there in next statement. The actual error was due to Excel package while parsing it and I got empty DataSet. var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(memoryStream);
                ds = excelReader.AsDataSet();
                excelReader.Close();